# How to check checkbox using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, checkbox

I have a problem with this checkbox. I tried to click searching element with id, name, XPath, CSS Selector and contains text and still I could not click on this checkbox. Additionally, I've tried with another site with similar HTML code and on this site, it was enough to look for id and click. Any ideas?

```html
<div class="agree-box-term">
    <input tabindex="75" id="agree" name="agree" type="checkbox" value="1">
    <label for="agree" class="checkbox-special">* Zapoznałam/em się z <a href="https://worldbox.pl/content/regulamin,27.html" target="_blank">Regulaminem sklepu internetowego</a> i akceptuję jego postanowienia.<br></label>
</div>
```

Here is my Python code  https://codeshare.io/5zo0Jj

Comment: check if it is inside any frame.If possible to share entire html?

Comment: yep, it is possible, where share u this code?

Comment: can you share here

Comment: https://codeshare.io/aVn1Q9

Comment: about 1115 line

Comment: Please share your test code here, this will help to quicker identify the problem.

Comment: Here is my Python code https://codeshare.io/5zo0Jj

Comment: @Hebrides : I have added code.please check

Comment: where, i could not see

Comment: Check answer section.

Comment: i ll tell u within 2 hours

Comment: You need to post an [mcve] of the problem here in your question. Also add what the result of your code is... error messages, a description of what works/what doesn't, etc.

Comment: problem, solved thank @KajalKundu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used javaScript Executor and it clicks on the element.However I have also checked webdriver click is not working.

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element_by_id("agree"))
```

Comment: Could you explain me why it works only with javaScript Executor?

Comment: When WebDriver click doesn’t work.you should use JavaScript executor to interact with element.However this is not a good practice but there is no alternatives.

Comment: But why it happens like that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this is, but in my experience some boxes don't accept click but do accept a 'mousedown' trigger.

**try:**

```
driver.execute_script('$("div.agree-box-term input#agree").trigger("mousedown")')
```

This solution does rely on jquery being on the page, if it's not we can write it in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Does your code contain nested html tags? For example:

```
<html>

    <div>

        <p> Some text </p>

        <html>
            That block can't be traversed!
        </html>

    </div>

</html>
```

Anything inside the second HTML tags **can't be traversed/accessed.** Try to see if that's the case.

---

In any other case the following code ran perfectly fine for your snippet:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#agree').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
r = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="form-order"]/div[2]/div[4]/label")
r.click()
```

Does this work for you? Sometimes it's just a question of selecting the right xpath, or adding the brackets after click.

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='form-order']/div[2]/div[4]/label"}